# JS : Running Array.every() to check API query params. Returning false

Tags: javascript, arrays, express

Attempting to check if an **API query param** is one that can be updated. `['age"]` 
So I'm checking against an *array of properties*. 
The value keeps coming back **false**
I've *console.log()*

- params
- properties array
- Outcome of checking params against properties array

```
    router.patch('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {

    const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
    const properties = ['name', 'age', 'email', 'password'];

    console.log(updates)
    console.log(properties)

    const validateUpdate = updates.every((item) => {
        properties.includes(item);
    });
    console.log(validateUpdate);
    try {
        if (!validateUpdate) {
            console.log(`Property not eligible for update: ${validateUpdate}`);
            return res.status(400).send('Property not eligible for update');

        }
        const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
            useFindAndModify: false,
            new: true,
            runValidators: true
        });
        res.status(200).send("update" + updateUser);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }

});
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `return` keyword inside the callback. If you use braces you must use `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return in the `every` callback, hence the callback is always returning `undefined` and thats translate to a falsy value.

To fix this just return the `includes` statement or remove the brackets `{}`.

```
const validateUpdate = updates.every((item) => {
    return properties.includes(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing return statement:

```
const validateUpdate = updates.every((item) => {
  properties.includes(item);
});
```

**Correct:**

```
const validateUpdate = updates.every((item) => properties.includes(item));
```